# How to compute the cookie for the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gerritcodereview scope?

Tags: git, cookies, google-api, google-oauth

Simple question, but I failed to find the documentation anywhere (though maybe my problem isn’t specific to that ᴀᴘɪ)

The aim of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gerritcodereview is to set a cookie which will be recognized by all websites that manage git repositories with write access (such cookie should be sent by the git client for all operations requiring authentication) for the current user.

How to compute the cookie from the `code` parameter returned by https://accounts.google.com ?

Comment: The scope you mentioned doesn't set a cookie. After you get the code from Google, you need to exchange it into a refresh token. And you can use the refresh token to get an Access token that can be sent in the request.  Try OAuth playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and also see code that others have written  https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-source-plugin

Comment: @nvnagr : But, the services concerned are using Oauth scopes to generate sessions cookies `(in the current case googlesource.com)` why I can’t do the same ?